# In Javascript how can I add additional statements to a function change()?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, getelementbyid

I believe there may be a simple solution to what I am looking for using Javascript. How can I add additional statements if my `function change(name)` is equal to a specific ID? For example:

```
function change(name) {
document.getElementById('Rectangle-container').style.display = 'none';

/* These require adding because the function's change(name) ID = Rectangle-container */

document.getElementById("ResultsTotalLiters").innerHTML = RectangleTotalLiters; 
document.getElementById("ResultsTurnoverTime").innerHTML = RectangleTurnoverTime;
document.getElementById("ResultsTotalTurnovers").innerHTML = RectangleTotalTurnovers

/* if the change is made so the active ID is oval-container, then 3 different statements need adding like so: */
document.getElementById('Oval-container').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("ResultsTotalLiters").innerHTML = OvalTotalLiters;
document.getElementById("ResultsTurnoverTime").innerHTML = OvalTurnoverTime;
document.getElementById("ResultsTotalTurnovers").innerHTML = OvalTotalTurnovers;

/**/
document.getElementById('Round-container').style.display = 'none';

/**/
document.getElementById('Oblong-container').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(name).style.display='block';
}
```

These need adding to the rectangle-container

```
document.getElementById("ResultsTotalLiters").innerHTML = RectangleTotalLiters;
document.getElementById("ResultsTurnoverTime").innerHTML = RectangleTurnoverTime;
document.getElementById("ResultsTotalTurnovers").innerHTML = RectangleTotalTurnovers;
```

These need adding to the oval-container

```
document.getElementById("ResultsTotalLiters").innerHTML = OvalTotalLiters;
document.getElementById("ResultsTurnoverTime").innerHTML = OvalTurnoverTime;
document.getElementById("ResultsTotalTurnovers").innerHTML = OvalTotalTurnovers;
```

Need adding to the round-container

```
document.getElementById("ResultsTotalLiters").innerHTML = RoundTotalLiters;
document.getElementById("ResultsTurnoverTime").innerHTML = RoundTurnoverTime;
document.getElementById("ResultsTotalTurnovers").innerHTML = RoundTotalTurnovers;
```

Need adding to the oblong-container

```
document.getElementById("ResultsTotalLiters").innerHTML = OblongTotalLiters;
document.getElementById("ResultsTurnoverTime").innerHTML = OblongTurnoverTime;
document.getElementById("ResultsTotalTurnovers").innerHTML = OblongTotalTurnovers;
```

Comment: Tbh I am still confused with what you are trying to achieve but by looks of it you trying to populate HTML elements with data based on some sort of scenario. 
The way I would approach it by replacing if with switch which will run a function change and pass more than 1 relative parameter to it,

Comment: @NashPL I have edited the question to provide a better explanation. Have you any new advice of answers you can provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your variables such that each type of shape variable is contained in an *object* rather than being a standalone variable. For example, instead of

```
RectangleTotalLiters
RectangleTurnoverTime
RectangleTotalTurnovers

OvalTotalLiters;
OvalTurnoverTime;
OvalTotalTurnovers;

// ...
```

you might consider an object structure like

```
const shapeInfo = {
  Rectangle: {
    totalLiters: <something>,
    turnoverTime: <something>,
    totalTurnovers: <something>,
  },
  Oval: {
    totalLiters: <something>,
    turnoverTime: <something>,
    totalTurnovers: <something>,
  },
  // ...
}
```

Then, you can write significantly DRY-er code:

```
const { totalLiters, turnoverTime, totalTurnovers } = shapeInfo[PoolShape];
/* assign to #ResultsTotalLiters, #ResultsTurnoverTime, #ResultsTotalTurnovers
```

For your `change` function, you might have a persistent array of all possible shapes, `forEach` over it, and hide the element if the `id` does not match `name`:

```
const shapes = ['Rectangle', 'Oval', 'Round', 'Oblong'];
function change(name) {
  shapes.forEach(id => {
    if (name !== id) document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  });
  document.getElementById(name).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Not sure it's exactly what he asks, but upvote for DRYness!

Comment: @CertainPerformance
 I am not sure an object structure would work as other parts of my code are also using these variables for different matters. Have you any other alternatives?

Comment: There's no reason why it should be impossible (or hard) to change your other code to work with the object. Worst case, refer to, eg, `shapeInfo.Oval.totalLiters` instead of `OvalTotalLiters`